# Is the principle of transfinite recursion equivalent to the axiom of replacement or to the axiom of regularity?

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6794/andreas-blass), Andreas Blass wrote:

> The axiom of regularity is clearly true with this understanding of what a set is. It expresses the idea that the stages of the cumulative hierarchy come in a well-ordered sequence.

One can easily convince oneself that this is true, and the main point here is that the usual ordering on the class of ordinals is a [well-founded relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation). This wikipedia article also states that a relation is well-founded if and only if it allows induction/recursion. Thus, from this point of view, it seems to me that the axiom of regularity is equivalent to the principle of transfinite recursion/induction.

But this contradicts the article http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/ by Hamkins which says that transfinite recursion is in fact the axiom of replacement.

How to resolve this seemingly paradoxical situation?

Comment: Well, the obvious problem is that you have not actually defined what you mean precisely by "the principle of transfinite recursion".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about two totally different "principles of transfinite recursion".  The first one is the statement that you can do transfinite induction on the relation $\in$ on the universe.  The second one is the statement that given any well-ordering $<$ on a set, you can do transfinite recursion using arbitrary class functions on that set.  Both of these statements involve a form of recursion or induction, but other than that they have little in common.

Comment: I understand your point but I'm still confused. Andreas Blass talks about the axiom of foundation expressing the idea that ordinals (he says "stages", but the stages are exactly the ordinals) are well-ordered. In my interpretation this is the induction principle which says: Prove sth for 0 and, assuming you have defined it for all y < x, prove it for the ordinal x. And this is what Hamkins is talking about.

Comment: I guess the point here is that the statement that the cumulative hierarchy is exactlx indexed be the ordinals presupposes the axiom of regularity.

Comment: Hamkins is talking about something _completely_ different.  He is talking about transfinite _recursion_, which says more or less that any recursive definition with a well-ordered index set whatsoever works.  This has absolutely nothing to do with saying that some _particular_ relation is well-founded, or is a well-order.  The gist is, Hamkins is talking about what you can _do_ with a well-ordered set once you have one, and Blass is talking about certain classes being well-ordered in the first place.

Comment: I think your confusion may be that you are conflating well-ordering, induction, and recursion.  These are three _different_ properties a structure can have.  Well-ordering and induction are always equivalent, but they are only equivalent to recursion in the presence of Replacement, which is what Hamkins is talking about.  On the other hand, Blass is talking about one particular structure being well-ordered (or well-founded).